# Crear task para eliminar usuarios sin puntos de montage en /home con ansible

Tags: linux, ansible

Tengo un listado de usuarios para dar de baja (BAJA_USUARIOS), pero sólo quiero eliminar aquellos que no tengan un punto de montage en su /home. (en caso que tengan sólo quiero mostrar un warning), tengo el siguiente codigo hecho con ansible:

```
- name: Comprueba si hay puntos de montage en el /home
  shell: "mount -l | grep bind | grep -ci {{ item }}"
  ignore_errors: yes
  check_mode: False
  loop: "{{ BAJA_USUARIOS }}"
  register: usuariosbaja

- name: elimina usuario sin puntos de montage en /home
  user:
    name: "{{ item }}"
    state: absent
    remove: yes
  when: item.stdout_lines == 0
  loop: usuariosbaja
```

Pero al ejecutarlo aparece el siguiente error:

```
TASK [osbasic : Comprueba si hay puntos de montage en el /home] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
 [WARNING]: Consider using the mount module rather than running 'mount'.  If you need to use command because mount is insufficient you can add 'warn: false' to this command task or set 'command_warnings=False' in ansible.cfg to get rid
of this message.

failed: [LGAUSUX10] (item=usuario1) => {"changed": true, "cmd": "mount -l | grep bind | grep -ci usuario1", "delta": "0:00:00.025089", "end": "2019-06-11 13:33:40.978563", "item": "itorrens", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": "2019-06-11 13:33:40.953474", "stderr": "", "stderr_lines": [], "stdout": "0", "stdout_lines": ["0"]}

TASK [osbasic : Comprueba si hay puntos de montage en el /home] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
...ignoring

TASK [osbasic : elimina usuario sin puntos de montage en /home] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [osbasic : elimina usuario sin puntos de montage en /home] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [LGAUSUX10]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Invalid data passed to 'loop', it requires a list, got this instead: usuariamblofs. Hint: If you passed a list/dict of just one element, try adding wantlist=True to your lookup invocation or use q/query instead of lookup."}
        to retry, use: --limit @/etc/ansible/osbasic.retry

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
LGAUSUX10                  : ok=9    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

Como podría poner la condición que si el resultado del comando es 0 entre en la segunda task y elimine el usuario?

Gracias!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes utilizar el modulo `stat` para verificar si una carpeta existe, en este caso, la carpeta seria `/home/{{user}}`.

```
- name: Comprueba si hay puntos de montage en el /home
  stat:
    path: '/home/{{item}}'
  loop: "{{ BAJA_USUARIOS }}"
  register: usuariosbaja

- debug:
    msg: "El usuario cuenta con una carpeta /home"
  when: item.stat.exists
  loop: '{{ usuariosbaja }}'

- name: elimina usuario sin puntos de montage en /home
  user:
    name: "{{ item }}"
    state: absent
    remove: yes
  when: item.stat.exists
  loop: '{{ usuariosbaja }}'
```

Espero haber ayudado.